# How to print in only one column if condition with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file bla.tsv (FS=`\t`):

```
id hub fil plop drift
3 187 0.91 bis XX
2 245 0.93     XX
4 250 0.70 bis XX
1 245 0.95 bis XX
```

And I want to print in the column `plop` the folowing string :

1. If `hub<200` print `intcv`
2. If `hub>200` and `fil<0.90` print `int`
3. If `hub>200` and `fil>0.90` don't print

In my example it would be :

```
id hub fil plop drift
3 187 0.91 intcr XX
2 245 0.93     XX
4 250 0.70 int XX
1 245 0.95 bis XX
```

I've write this but did not have a good result :

```
awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '
   NR==1{print $0} ; 
   (NR>1 && $2<200){$(NF-1)="intcv";  print $0,$(NF-1) }; 
   (NR>1 && $2>200 && $3<0.90) {$(NF-1)="int";  print $0,$(NF-1) }
' bla.tsv > result.tsv
```

Do you have an idea how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please ensure that you have no typos in your test (e.g. `intcr` vs. `intcv`). Also, please describe in what way your attempt did not yield a "good result". In addition, if you write "if (hub>200) ... don't print": Do you mean to change the 4th column to an empy field or to simply not change the existing value? And what happens if `hub` is exactly 200 / `fil` is exactly 0.90?

Comment: What actions to take when `hub == 200` and/or `fil == 0.9` ?

Comment: Note `intcv` in your code, but `intcr` in the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } NR != 1 { $4 = ($2 < 200 ? "intcv" : ($3 < 0.9 ? "int" : $4)) }; 1' file
```

This is using `(condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false)`, which is also known as a "[ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)".  It uses this twice to arrive at the correct value for `$4`.

The trailing `1` at the end of the code could be replaced by `{ print }`, i.e. an unconditional `print` statement that prints the possibly modified line.  For each input line, the code goes through whatever logic that it needs to go through, and then, at the end, prints out the modified line.

The result of running this on your data:

```
id      hub     fil     plop    drift
3       187     0.91    intcv   XX
2       245     0.93            XX
4       250     0.70    int     XX
1       245     0.95    bis     XX
```

Expanded into an `if`-statement, the code

```
$4 = ($2 < 200 ? "intcv" : ($3 < 0.9 ? "int" : $4))
```

would look like

```
if ($2 < 200)
    $4 = "intcv"
else if ($3 < 0.9)
    $4 = "int"
```

or, on a single line,

```
if ($2 < 200) $4 = "intcv"; else if ($3 < 0.9) $4 = "int";
```

... and there would be `else $4 = $4` at the end, but we can obviously skip that assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to print **all** lines, with changes in **some**, you can just do the changes and then append `1` to the very end, it means *true* and the default is executed (= print the line).

So for your script, it means: simply remove all `print` statements and add `1` and you should be done.

```bsh
awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" ' 
   (NR>1 && $2<200){$(NF-1)="intcv"}; 
   (NR>1 && $2>200 && $3<0.90) {$(NF-1)="int"}
1' bla.tsv > result.tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        f[$i] = i
    }
    next
}
{
    if ( ($(f["hub"]) < 200) ) {
        $(f["plop"]) = "intcv"
    }
    else if ( ($(f["hub"]) > 200) && ($(f["fil"]) < 0.90) ) {
        $(f["plop"]) = "int"
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk bla.tsv
3       187     0.91    intcv   XX
2       245     0.93            XX
4       250     0.70    int     XX
1       245     0.95    bis     XX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign to `$4` to modify the field. It rebuilds the field separators, but with single tabs as separators, that doesn't break anything.

```
$ awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '
   NF < 3 {print; next}   
   ($2 < 200) { $4 = "intcv" }; 
   ($2 > 200 && $3 < 0.90) {$4 = "int" };
   ($2 > 200 && $3 > 0.90) { /* nothing */ };
   {print}
' bla.tsv
id      hub     fil     plop    drift
3       187     0.91    intcv   XX
2       245     0.93            XX
4       250     0.70    int     XX
1       245     0.95    bis     XX
```

Note that the conditions here are checked sequentially, which matters if you change them so that more than one can match. I added the `NF < 3` case to deal with empty lines. Also, you may want to check what you want to do when `$2 == 200` or `$3 == 0.90`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{if($2 < 200){$4="intcv"}else{if(($2 >200) && ($3<0.90)){$4="int"}}}1' filename
```

Output:

```
id hub fil plop drift
3 187 0.91 intcv XX
2 245 0.93     XX
4 250 0.70 int XX
1 245 0.95 bis XX
```